# Access array in c# code from python script

Tags: c#, arrays, python-2.6

How can I use the subprocess module in python to access elements from array in c# code?

Comment: a very hacky way would be to output the array elements to the console as text and redirect stdout, then parse it. You might want to look at IronPython, it works in reverse, where C# would be the host process, but it allows for communication between .NET languages and Python.

Comment: but the one i'm thinking to use is "subprocess module" in python, since i do not use a stand a lone python program, am using Blender and i wanna to run the C# code and use its output (the array i want) to access object in Blender scene .. that is ..

Answer (score 1):

You could use [IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/), a Python interpreter created by Microsoft that natively supports .NET (but not capable of loading native-code modules like h5py).

You could also use [Python.NET](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/), a Python module providing an interface to .NET components.

But there are more ways...

Comment: is this python ( i mean python.NET ) is compatible with the one used for Blender 2.49 which need python2.6 ??

Comment: Python.NET is a library compatible with a standard Python interpreter. There is also a version that is linked against Python 2.6.

Comment: so, what about using subprocess module in python ?? but i don know how to use it exactly ? is there any help ?

Comment: Yes, http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html is a documentation for the Python.NET module, the documentation for the subprocess module should be available from the Python home page...